# Oracle Group with multiple condition

Tags: oracle

I have a scenario where I need to fetch all the records within an ID for the one source along with other source. Given below is my input set of records.

```
ID  Source  MIND    CIND    QIND
1   IBM      Y       Y       M
1   TCS    NULL    NULL      D
1   CTS    NULL    NULL      D
2   TCS    Y       NULL      D
2   CTS    NULL    Y         M
2   TCS    NULL   NULL       D
3   TCS    NULL   NULL       D
3   CTS    NULL   Y          M
3   CTS    NULL   NULL       D
5   TCS    Y      Y          M
5   TCS    NULL   NULL       D
```

From the above records, I need to select all the records with source include only TCS and CTS within that same ID group and other source should not be there for the same ID.Also, we need to fetch only those records where at least one record in that ID group with CIND='Y'
 In the above scenario even though the ID=1 have a source as IBM along with TCS and CTS,so this record should not be considered.In case of ID=2, we can fetch this record as it have both TCS and CTS within the same group.Same with the case of ID=3.But in the case of ID=5 I dont want to fetch that records, as we have only one source within that group.

Now within that group which satisfy above condition(ID=2 and ID=3) I need to fetch all the records based on the condition on priority basis. If there is any record in a group whose MIND value is 'Y'.For example within the group ID=2; I have one record with MIND='Y'.After taking that record, I need to select all other records in that group whose SOURCE value is same as that of the record with MIND='Y'.In this MIND='Y' is for source='TCS'.So I will take the other record whose source='TCS'

But if there is no records within the group with MIND='Y' , we need to take the record with QIND='M'.In case of group with ID=3, all the records MIND value is null. So we need to fetch the record whose QIND='M' and other records with same source within the group.In group with ID= 3 QIND='M' is for CTS, so I will consider other records with source='CTS' in that group

I have written a query for the same.But it will not work as expected.Either it will take records with QIND='M' or MIND='Y' based on the condition I give in the query.I want the query in such a way that if MIND='Y' is null for all the records within the group then we need to go for QIND='M'

```
select ID,MIND,CIND,QIND,source
from MYTABLE a where  source <>'IBM' and 
exists(select 1 from MYTABLE B where source <>'IBM' 
 AND A.ID=B.ID AND A.ROWID<>B.ROWID AND B.SOURCE<>A.SOURCE)
and a.source in(select C.source from MYTABLE C where  C.MIND='Y'
and a.ID=C.ID)
and not exists(select 1 from MYTABLE D where D.source='IBM' 
 AND A.ID=D.ID) 
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM MYTABLE D WHERE A.ID=D.ID AND D.CIND='Y')
```

My expected output is given below

```
ID  Source  MIND    CIND    QIND
2   TCS     Y       NULL    D
2   TCS   NULL      NULL    D
3   CTS   NULL      Y       M
3   CTS   NULL     NULL      D
```

---

As requested by Tim

```
ID  Source  MIND    CIND    QIND
6   IBM      Y      Y       D
6   TCS    NULL     Y       M
6   CTS    NULL     Y       D

ID  Source  MIND    CIND    QIND
7   IBM     NULL    Y       D
7   TCS     NULL    Y       M
7   CTS     NULL    Y       D
7   TCS     NULL    Y       D
```

Comment: My first requirement is to identify the groups which satisfy the condition that ; within the group two source should be there and that source should consist only of TCS and CTS. So we will get group with ID=2 and ID=3.

Comment: Now within that group I need to fetch all the records based on the condition  on priority basis. If there is any record in a group whose MIND value is 'Y'.For example within the group ID=2; I have one record with MIND='Y'.After taking that record, I need to select all other records in that group whose SOURCE value is same as that of the record with MIND='Y'.In this MIND='Y' is for source='TCS'.So I will take the other record whose source='TCS'

Comment: The second part of your query sounds very complex and is poorly explained.  You may refer to my deleted answer to get started.

Comment: Hi Tim, Actually I am not able to see the answer which has given by you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach below joins your original table to two subqueries which refine the result set the way you want.  The first subquery, aliased as `t2`, finds `ID` groups where both `CTS` and `TCS` are present, with no other sources present.  In addition, matching `ID` groups must have at least one yes `CIND` value.

The second subquery implements the logic you want for choosing a source for matching `ID` groups.  For those groups having a non `NULL` `MIND` value, we take the source from that record.  Otherwise we take the source from the record having `QIND = 'M'`.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM MYTABLE t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM MYTABLE
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'TCS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
           SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'CTS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
           SUM(CASE WHEN Source NOT IN ('TCS', 'CTS') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND
           SUM(CASE WHEN CIND = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID,
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN MIND IS NOT NULL THEN Source END),
                 MAX(CASE WHEN QIND = 'M' THEN Source END)) AS Source
    FROM MYTABLE
    GROUP BY ID
) t3
    ON t1.ID = t3.ID AND
       t1.Source = t3.Source
```

Comment: This is wrong.  Left up temporarily for the OP as a suggestion.

Comment: Hi Tim , this query will give my first portion correctly.Case 2 is that from the output is this query I need to find out whether any record which I got from the above query, have a value in MIND column within the group. If it is there I need to fetch all the records having the same source(which have value in MIND column) from that group.Here in the case of ID=2, source TCS have value populated in MIND column, so I need to fetch all the records in that group whose source is TCS

Comment: In case if I am not able to find any record in CASE 2, I need to check CASE 3 condition. CASE 3 condition is that I need to select the record within the group whose value='M' in QIND column. If it is there I need to fetch all the records having the same source(which have value='M' in QIND column) from that group.So in this scenrio for ID=3 , CTS is the record who have value ='M' in QIND column, so I will pick all the records from group whose ID=3 and source='CTS'

Comment: Thanks Tim.But in the case of a group where we have IBM(ID=1), its fetching that IBM record alone from the group, which is not expected.

Comment: @GIN You can't be getting that output from the sample data and my query.  Please edit your question with data where this edge case happens.

Comment: In the scenario with ID=6, I am getting the IBM record.In the scenario with ID=7 I am getting both the TCS records. I have added the sample records in my original post

Comment: @GIN Sorry...the logic in my middle subquery was wrong.  Please try it again.

Comment: Thanks a ton Tim. Its working from initial round of testing. Will let you know if I face some problem in middle

Comment: Keep me posted.